# Jquery prop required error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue here.

**Prop function:**
So I have an issue with setting two options to required. One works and one doesn't.
`.prop('required',true);` works for `#additional_here_about_other_field`. This sets the field to required. But the same `.prop('required',true);` doesn't work on `#additional_who_is_your_orthodontist_field`. I want this field to be required as well but it doesn't work.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 
 if(jQuery("#additional_here_about_other_field").length > 0){
  jQuery("#additional_here_about_other_field").hide();
  jQuery("#additional_how_did_u_hear_about_harp").change(function(){
   if(jQuery(this).val() == 'Other (please specify)'){ jQuery("#additional_here_about_other_field").show().prop('required',true); }
   else { jQuery("#additional_here_about_other_field").hide(); }
  });
 }
 if(jQuery("#additional_who_is_your_orthodontist_field").length > 0){
  jQuery("#additional_who_is_your_orthodontist_field").hide();
  jQuery("#additional_how_did_u_hear_about_harp").change(function(){
   if(jQuery(this).val() == 'Orthodontist Referral'){ jQuery("#additional_who_is_your_orthodontist_field").show().prop('required',true); }
   else { jQuery("#additional_who_is_your_orthodontist_field").hide(); }
  });
 }
});
```

```
HTML snippet
```

```html
<select name="additional_how_did_u_hear_about_harp" id="additional_how_did_u_hear_about_harp" class="select " data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder="How Did You Hear About The Harp?" >
 <option value=""  selected='selected'></option>
 <option value="Patient" >Patient</option>
 <option value="Orthodontist Referral" >Orthodontist Referral</option>
 <option value="Trade Show" >Trade Show</option>
 <option value="Mailer" >Mailer</option>
 <option value="Other (please specify)" >Other (please specify)</option>
</select>

<div class="clear"></div>
<p>  
 <input type="text" class="input-text " name="additional_here_about_other_field" id="additional_here_about_other_field" placeholder="Other (please specify)"   value=""  />
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p>  
 <input type="text" class="input-text " name="additional_who_is_your_orthodontist" id="additional_who_is_your_orthodontist" placeholder="Who is your orthodontist?"   value=""  />
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Please add your html code to your snippet

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen added html snippet

Comment: Please post separate problems in separate questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have a misspelling in your Input field `additional_who_is_your_orthodontist` but you query said `additional_who_is_your_orthodontist_field`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($("#additional_here_about_other_field").length > 0) {
    $("#additional_here_about_other_field").hide();
    $("#additional_how_did_u_hear_about_harp").change(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 'Other (please specify)') {
        $("#additional_here_about_other_field").show().prop('required', true);
      } else {
        $("#additional_here_about_other_field").hide();
      }
    });
  };
  if ($("#additional_who_is_your_orthodontist").length > 0) {
    $("#additional_who_is_your_orthodontist").hide();
    $("#additional_how_did_u_hear_about_harp").change(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 'Orthodontist Referral') {
       $("#additional_who_is_your_orthodontist").show().attr('required', true);
      } else {
        $("#additional_who_is_your_orthodontist").hide();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="additional_how_did_u_hear_about_harp" id="additional_how_did_u_hear_about_harp" class="select " data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder="How Did You Hear About The Harp?">
 <option value=""  selected='selected'></option>
 <option value="Patient" >Patient</option>
 <option value="Orthodontist Referral" >Orthodontist Referral</option>
 <option value="Trade Show" >Trade Show</option>
 <option value="Mailer" >Mailer</option>
 <option value="Other (please specify)" >Other (please specify)</option>
</select>

<div class="clear"></div>
<p>
  <input type="text" class="input-text" name="additional_here_about_other_field" id="additional_here_about_other_field" placeholder="Other (please specify)" value="" />
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p>
  <input type="text" class="input-text" name="additional_who_is_your_orthodontist" id="additional_who_is_your_orthodontist" placeholder="Who is your orthodontist?" value="" />
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for spotting that